# "Openoffice Calc" Comparing time using IF always returns false

Tags: calc

i am using the following data (Cells are formatted for time (24hr) 13:37) and IF functions but they always return false for some reason

Cell A1  17:00

Cell A2  17:10

Cell B1 17:00

Cell B2 16:30

Cell A4  =IF(A2>A1;"true";"false")
Cell B4 =IF(B2>B1:"true";"false")

both of these return False where as i think the A Cell If Function should return true or am i missing something

Thanks
John

Comment: Are you sure these are times and not strings that happen to look like times? Opening a fresh document and inputting these times, I get `true` for the first result

Comment: They were definitely set to time format hh:mm but after you comment i changed them to hh:mm:ss format and it worked fine then i changed them back to hh:mm and it worked so obviously there was something weird happening with the time format. Thanks for giving me a direction to look as i didn't think that would be the problem